# "Error in `$<-.data.frame" error in as.factor conversion

Tags: dataframe, type-conversion

I am new to R. I am trying to convert into factors using as.factor(). While all other conversions happen smoothly, only 1 gets stuck throwing up the following error:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, CofMind_1, value = integer(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 112

My code below:

```
CMD.LongF <- dplyr::select(mainF, ResponseId, Age, Gender, Education, Polview, CofMind_1, CofMind_2, Align_1, Align_2, NA_1, NA_2) %>%
  gather(CofMind_1, CofMind_2, Align_1, Align_2, key = "Item", value = "Score", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  separate(col = Item, into = c("Variable",'Item'), sep = "_") %>%
  arrange(ResponseId)
  cmdcF=CMD.LongF #longformat
```

Here are the main factors of our study:

- **ResponseIds** (Unique for each participants)
- **CofMind** (Change of mind for each participant for each pair of items)
- **Align** (Interest alignment for each participant with the expert)
- **Items** (1 and 2).

Here we set all to factors and re-order their levels for illustration purposes:

```
  cmdcF$ResponseId=as.factor(cmdcF$ResponseId)
cmdcF$Gender=as.factor(cmdcF$Gender)
cmdcF$Education=as.factor(cmdcF$Education)
cmdcF$Age=as.factor(cmdcF$Age)
cmdcF$Polview=as.factor(cmdcF$Polview)
cmdcF$CofMind=as.factor(cmdcF$CofMind)
cmdcF$Align=as.factor(cmdcF$Align)
cmdcF$Item=as.factor(cmdcF$Item)

#re_name
```

I am working with the instructor's code and their chunk runs fine. This is for a class project. The explanation for what I am trying to achieve is already provided in the comments with the code.

The structure is as follows:

> str(cmdcF)
> 'data.frame':   112 obs. of  10 variables:

$ ResponseId: Factor w/ 28 levels "R_1CBeSOZYxg9lrFk",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...

$ Age       : Factor w/ 15 levels "","16","21","22",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 12 12 ...

$ Gender    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Female","Male",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

$ Education : Factor w/ 6 levels "Bachelor's degree",..: 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 2 2 ...

$ Polview   : Factor w/ 4 levels "Neutral","Slightly conservative",..: 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 4 4 ...

$ NA_1      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...

$ NA_2      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...

$ Variable  : chr  "CofMind" "CofMind" "Align" "Align" ...

$ Item      : chr  "1" "2" "1" "2" ...

$ Score     : num  0 0 13.6 13.9 0 ...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. "CofMind" is not a column head.

Comment: Looks more suitable for comments section than for answers